# Making AJAX Requests To Rabl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rabl

I have an action rendering rabl templates. When I call it in the browser address bar, I see the json response in the browser. But while making AJAX calls, I cant seem to get a success response. It always gets an error.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/user/check_user_availibility',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                username: us,
                email: em
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert('success');
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            error: function(d,g,f){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what happens when you append `.json` to the url?

Comment: I think you just solved my problem. Complete idiocy on my part. I apologize. Not only had I names my file .html.rabl instead of .json.rabl, but I forgot to put a .json at the end of the url.